# maximal interval of existence of $\dot{x} = f(t,x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I was doing some exercises, and i met this one, that i really don't know how to solve. Does anybody know how to solve it? Also, hints are very (if not more) appreciated! Thanks very much

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that according or similar to the Grönwall lemma, you get an upper bound $u$ with $|x(\pm t)|\le u(t)$ that is the solution of
$$
\dot u=Cu^M, ~~ u(0)=|x(0)|
$$
This is separable and further symbolically solvable
$$
u(t)^{1-M}-u(0)^{1-M}=-C(M-1)t
$$
This has a singularity where $u(0)^{1-M}=C(M-1)t$, inside that range the solution of the original DE is finite and thus well-defined and extendable. Thus
$$T\ge \frac{|x(0)|^{-(M-1)}}{C(M-1)}$$

Comment: Thanks! Yes, now it makes sense. But how do I prove the "gronwall lemma " in this case? I tried to adapt a classical proof but it does not work (i think)